# Installing LLVM / Clang 6+ on centos 7

Tags: llvm, centos7

The [llvm-toolset-7](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-sclo-rh-testing/llvm-toolset-7-5.0.1-4.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) comes with clang 5 but i need to install software that is compatible only with clang 6+. How can i install a more recent clang?

Answer (score 2):

You can download the llvm source [here](http://releases.llvm.org/download.html). Then follow [these steps](https://llvm.org/docs/CMake.html) to build from source. llvm 6+ will include clang 6+.

Comment: I have installed llvm based on your guide.You can find the output https://pastebin.com/8YishnCJ . i installed it as follows https://pastebin.com/41HNxHrk . However i don't see the clang++ binary

Answer (score 1):

Install the [`llvm-toolset-6.0`](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_developer_tools/2018.4/html-single/using_clang_and_llvm_toolset/index).